# If one made a mezonot on a shehakol, should he correct it?

Tags: mezonot-beracha, shehakol-beracha

As we learned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25596/mistaken-shehakol-correct-it), if one makes a shekahol, it covers the mezonot food. What if the case was flipped around, i.e, one made a mezonot on a food that was shehakol?

1. What if he realized mid-eating; should he correct it?
2. What if realized once he finished; what is the proper procedure?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82817/759

Answer (score 1):

[Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Safek_Brachot_LeHaKel#cite_ref-24) says

> Bracha Rishona: After the fact if one recited mezonot on anything
> besides water or salt, one fulfilled one's obligation.

He quotes the following authorities:

> Chaye Adam (v. 1, 58:3), Halacha Brurah 206:7, Igrot Moshe OC 4:40.
> Ritva Brachot 2:16 writes that after the fact Mezonot is effective
> even for bread.